# update progress of android progress bar inside listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-progressbar, android-download-manager

I'm downloading files by using android download manager. Files are multiple, and I'm showing their progress inside of listview. my code is working fine but when my downloads gets more than 4 or 5 the listview gets very slow, infact the whole app gets slow. In a few moment it gets stuck and I've to forcibly close because phone also gets hanged.
here is my code to update listview.

```
private class UpdaterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    boolean isRunning = true;
    boolean progressBusy = false;
    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (isRunning) {


            if(progressBusy==true){

            }
            else{
                progressBusy = true;
                publishProgress();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
        super.onProgressUpdate();
        try {
            progressBusy = false;
            if (mScrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                int start = Lv_DownloadItems.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for (int i = start, j = Lv_DownloadItems
                        .getLastVisiblePosition(); i <= j; i++) {
                    View view = Lv_DownloadItems.getChildAt(i - start);
                    DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    q.setFilterById(Long.parseLong(progress_ids
                            .get(i)));
                    final Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    long bytes_downloaded = cursor
                            .getInt(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
                    int bytes_total = cursor
                            .getInt(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

                    int len1 = (int)(bytes_downloaded * 100 / bytes_total);

                    int columnIndex = cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);

                    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                    progress.setProgress(len1);

                    TextView txtStatus = (TextView) view
                            .findViewById(R.id.percentage);
                    // txtStatus.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
                    txtStatus.setText(String.valueOf(len1) + "%");
                    cursor.close();


                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ec) {
            ec.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I call this async task at onResume

```
UpdaterAsyncTask mUpdater = new UpdaterAsyncTask();
            mUpdater.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
                    (Void) null);
```

I'm totally gets stuck and don't know where i'm wrong, please help me. Any help would be much appreciated. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Thread.sleep(16);`. 16 ms ? That is short. onProgressUpdate will take much more time than that. But what is more: if you call publishProgress() so often they will all stack up as onProgressUpdate will only later get called when the OS has time to do that on the UI thread. With a little adaptation you can prevent an to early calling of publishProgress(). Add to the asynctask a`volatile boolean progressBusy = false;` Set it to true before calling publishProgress(). Set it to false again in onProgressUpdate. In doInBackground do not call publishProgress() if progressBusy is true.

Comment: I've set progressBusy = true; before publishProgress() in doInBackground and I'm not calling publishProgress() if progressBusy is true. But now progress is not being updated :(

Comment: I've it is working and it is improved to some extent but the problem is still there. I'm going to edit the code like what you've said. plz have a look

Comment: `progressBusy = false;`. You have that as first statement in onProgressUpdate. That is the wrong place. That will not help if you use 200 ms. You should put that as last statement. When the code is done.

Comment: I've added it in last but no luck :( how much time should i use?

Comment: First measure the executing time of onProgressUpdate. But meanwhile start with 2000 or more. You have time consuming code there. It could benefit from a multi core processor.

Comment: I've increased the time now, it is not being stuck now. But I'm searching files from internet in another fragment of same activity. Now search giving me null after 4,5 downloads. I'm using async task for search.

Comment: Ok, dude, it is working but when i exit this async task doesn't stop, can you tell me how can i stop that async task. Thanks for your responses, it is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Thank you dude, it worked and i stopped the async task onPause. Thank you so much for your help. You saved my lot of time. Thank you :)

Comment: `when i exit`. What do you mean? When is that? Make `boolean isRunning = true;` more 'global` so someone else can make it false at exit.

Comment: it was when i exit from the fragment, i mean when i switch the fragment. there was need to stop that async task otherwise it was creating problems for other async tasks coz maximum 5 async can run at a time. Thank you, any ways :)

Answer (score 0):

Well from what I can see from the little code you have provided us,

first and for most, you are not calling your stop() method any ware so I assume you are locked in an infinite loop.

```
 public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }
```

On [Google's Android Developer Documentation site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) they have an outstanding example on how to effectevly use AsyncTask class correctly and readable.

Hope it helps.